# remove annotation only which is not in my drawing region in MapKit iOS Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, mapkit

I want to keep only those annotations which are in my polygon region of map view. How can remove remaining annotations from map using swift 4.2.
here is my code

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        mapView?.removeOverlays(mapView!.overlays)
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let coordinate = mapView!.convert(touch.location(in: mapView),      toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
            points.append(coordinate)
        }
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let coordinate = mapView!.convert(touch.location(in: mapView),       toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
            points.append(coordinate)
            let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: points, count: points.count)
            mapView!.addOverlay(polyline)
        }
    }
     override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
                let polygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: &points, count: points.count)
                mapView?.addOverlay(polygon)
    }

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if overlay is MKPolyline {
            let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            polylineRenderer.strokeColor = .blue
            polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 5
            return polylineRenderer
        } else if overlay is MKPolygon {
            let polygonView = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            polygonView.fillColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
            return polygonView
        }
        return MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    }
```

Comment: under drawing region you mean the rendered part of the map that's visible or you are actually adding poligons and want to remove them outside of that closed area?

Comment: @BencePattogato i am adding MKPolygon and want to remove all annotations outside of polygon. just keep inside of polygon.

Comment: first or second option exactly? :D

Comment: There is no need to remove annotations. They are tony lightweight objects. If the annotation is not in the visible region it has no annotation view.

Comment: @matt when i am getting region through polygon then not setting region to map view . just want to remove outsider annotations..

Comment: @BencePattogato please see my comment.

Comment: But there is no polygon in your question. Did you ask the wrong question?

Comment: @matt please see my updated questions.